# Web host keeps blocking server feeding me XML via POST request

Tags: firewall, webserver

I recently set up a site on a web hosting provider.

The purpose of the site is to receive XML messages (via POST) from satellite comms data centre and store them in a database. Frequency of the messages can be up to one a minute, but the data centre also retries sending if the POST fails. I'm not sure what the retry freq. is.

After about a month of working fine, the web host starting blocking the data centre IP. Working with tech support we tried changing the permissions on the php file receiving the POST requests and white listing the server IP in the web host firewall. Despite these changes (and clearing the block) the server IP would get flagged again.

Is there anything else we should try? I still have two years of hosting left so I don't really want to change providers.

Comment: *Is there anything else we should try?* If sending/receiving your XML messages is legitimate, tell your hosting provider not to mess with them.

Comment: They are legit, the web host tech support doesn't know why they are being flagged and blocked. Is that poor service? If so, I better change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service provider.  (There are probably other options, like setting up a VPN or obscuring your traffic, but really, if your hosting is playing silly buggers over something like that, the best solution is to find one that won't.   Its not like hosting providers are a rare commodity).

Comment: I just didn't want to waste the money seeing I'd already paid up. But it sounds like I'm going to have to change like you said.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but it sounds like you are looking for a technical answer when you really need a legal one !! I can be a bit harsh, and, of-course I have not seen your contract, but assuming you are within the terms of service, I'd demand my money back for breach of contract/misleading conduct/interference with business relations or a similar tort - and if they did not refund your payment I'd go to a small claims court - of-course, I'm making assumptions that you are posting from a jurisdiction with a practical legal system !

Comment: If the IP address of the server is being blocked, technicians telling you to change perms on a local file are acting incompetently, as network changes are not tied in to file level changes.  The only way to solve the underlying problem will be to isolate what is causing the block and get your ISP to fix that.   I wonder if you have signed up with a cheap hosting provider who doesn't actually want you as a customer because you are using more resources then they would like.

Comment: Yep they are a cheapish hosting provider, but I'm using hardly any bandwidth. Took your advice and transferred providers, domain name and all. Since they were cheap its not too much of a hit to the wallet. New host comes highly recommended so lets see how it goes. Thanks for answering my question.